# Avoid dead links in onenote

Tags: microsoft-onenote, hyperlink, microsoft-onenote-2013

In Onenote, I can create links to pages or paragraphs. But when I delete target, link will be dead. Is there a way to warn me before deleting ? Or is there a way to see the map of links and target pages?

Comment: It should detect the change and update the link automatically. At least it works for me when I move pages about. Can you show the steps to reproduce this problem?

Comment: @ytk OK! Thank you, it will update when moved between notebook but if you delete the target and empty the recycle bin, then it can not update link and I want to warn me before deleting.

Comment: As suggested in [my answer on Software Recommendations](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/23425/14982), shifting to using a personal wiki will remove this issue.